# Get value of TextArea in AngularJS service

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a service used by a controller/view, when a button is pressed within the view it fires a method in the service. This service needs access to the value of a TextArea within that view.

Currently i have:

within the service:

```
cancelClick: function() {
    console.log(angular.element('commentText').val());
},
```

And then within the view:

```
<textarea class="cancel-comment form-control" rows="8" id="commentText" placeholder="Notes" x-ng-model="cancelNotes"></textarea>

<div class="text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-cancel" id="cancel-order" ng-click="orderService.cancelClick()">{{'CANCEL THIS ORDER' | translate}}</button>                
</div>
```

Now the button click is working however the `console.log` print a `undefined`.

What is the right way to get the value from the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`commentText is Id` in your view.

```
  cancelClick: function() {
        console.log(angular.element('#commentText').val());
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

In angular services should not have access, nor manipulate DOM objects. Instead you can bind to your view with your controller, and still store/manipulate text with your service:

**[The Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JgBMTbJUqKs7vkD2SFQ4?p=preview)**

**The Markup**

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <h3 class="text-success">Test Area</h3>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" id="commentText" placeholder="Notes" ng-model="mainCtrl.text"></textarea>
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="mainCtrl.saveToLocalStorage()">Save Changes</button>
```

**The JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['tempDataStorageService', function(tempDataStorageService) {

  var myCtrl = this;

    myCtrl.text = angular.copy(tempDataStorageService.text);

    myCtrl.localStorage = tempDataStorageService;

    myCtrl.saveToLocalStorage = function () {
      tempDataStorageService.text = angular.copy(myCtrl.text);
    }

}]);


app.factory('tempDataStorageService', function() {
    // The service object
    var storage = this;

    storage.text;

    // return the service object
    return storage;
});
```